# how to customize the orientation in Titanium appcelerator 5.0.2

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I want to fix portrait mode in all time 
I tried it in titanium sdk 4, the code is

```
if (Ti.Platform.osname == 'android'){
    Ti.Gesture.addEventListener('orientationchange', function(e) 
        {           
            Ti.Android.currentActivity.setRequestedOrientation(Ti.Android.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        });
}
```

it is not works in titanium sdk 5.0.2

Comment: maybe [this link](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/123939/lock-sreen-orientation-on-android) will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a guide specifically about locking the orientation:

https://appcelerator.github.io/appc-docs/latest/#!/guide/Orientation

Comment: Could you mark my answer as the right answer so other people can see?